# type hint npt.NDArray number of axis

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given I have the number of axes, can I specify the number of axes to the type hint npt.NDArray (from `import numpy.typing as npt`)

i.e. if I know it is a 3D array, how can I do `npt.NDArray[3, np.float64]`

Comment: [`np.typing.NDArray`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.NDArray) doc says that it is for "typing arrays with a given dtype and unspecified shape".

Comment: I see, thanks, so I should use `np.ndarray[shape, dtype]`?

Comment: Seems like `arr: np.ndarray[Tuple[Literal[2], Literal[3]], np.dtype[np.int_]] = np.array(data)` does the job for me on Python 3.9 and 3.10. Also see related [numpy issue #16544](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16544)

Comment: Thank you for you help, that should be it. One more question, what does the number means>

Comment: The number are for the exact shape of the array, as discussed in the numpy issue it seems that there is still now way to just declare the rank of the array, but something like `ndarray[Shape[:, :, :], dtype]` should be available in the future.

Comment: thanks for the information, is there any way to close the question now? (Also the pep linked suggested creating a newtype for each axis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Python 3.9 and 3.10 the following does the job for me:

```py
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
arr: np.ndarray[Tuple[Literal[2], Literal[3]], np.dtype[np.int_]] = np.array(data)
```

It is a bit cumbersome, but you might follow [numpy issue #16544](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16544) for future development on easier specification.

In particular, for now you must declare the full shape and can't only declare the rank of the array.

In the future something like `ndarray[Shape[:, :, :], dtype]` should be available.