# How to provide SHAPE hint on Numpy NDArray?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, typing

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray

#I wanna do
rows = 3
columns = 5
def func(x: NDArray[(rows,columns),float]):
        pass
#I am trying to say the input matrix should have 3 rows and 5 columns.
```

I have tried nptying, but their latest version require Shape input, which also requires strings. How can I directly create shape hints on Numpy NDArray using integers?

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72845616/type-hint-npt-ndarray-number-of-axis